# How do you save document mongoose without schema

Tags: mongoose

i have a Object: game.

```
    game = { 
    gameId: "916304e8-c2ee-4d54-8ef1-8a5d75c7ba90", 
    gameName: "What Kind Of Person Are You Really?",
    score: 10
    }
      var thingSchema = new Schema({
gameId: String, gameName: String
}, { strict: false });
      var Thing= mongoose.model('Thing', thingSchema );
      var thing = new Thing(game);
      thing.save()
```

But score is not saved to the db!

Comment: use an object: `{name:String, email:String, otherProperties: {}}`

Comment: I have an object from the previous game. Now I want to add but not added to the variable score

Comment: Are you assigning properties like this: `game.score=100`? If so, you instead need to do it like this: `game.set('score',100)` otherwise things don't work when using `strict:false`